# Can Facebook Timeline be updated via an API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-timeline

Is it possible to update Facebook Timeline using some sort of an API?

Say for instance if I wanted to upload a large amount of content for the reverse chronological history of the timeline?

Comment: If you were referring to information in the past, it is not possible. E.g. You cannot currently use the API to post a life event to your past.

Comment: @phwd I don't mean a personal profile, I was talking about a Business Page with the facebook-api

Comment: This questions is more suitable on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Creator - Not really. a) the post is quite old and b) there's not a specific coding question being asked - just "can I do this?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

See: [Facebook Graph API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) at "Publishing":

> You can publish to the Facebook graph by issuing HTTP POST requests to
>   the appropriate connection URLs, using an [access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication).

For more detailed information, see also [Graph API reference for a single "post"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

Also good reading is the [Open Graph tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) and [Best Practices guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/bestpractices/).

<sup>*Disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself, so there could be some limitations I'm not aware of.*</sup>

Comment: You're no longer able to create posts on your timeline via the API: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/07/31/platform-update-publish-permission/. You can still do it for Facebook Pages though.